# Error while executing Google Prediction API Command line Sample

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, google-api, google-prediction

I have downloaded the sample command line program for prediction api and imported in eclipse as mention [here](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/prediction-cmdline-sample/instructions.html) .

I have imported that sample program and replaced the content of client_secrets.json with values of file which i downloaded from api console as mentioned in the above link .

I have built the model using [standalone explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/prediction/v1.6/prediction.trainedmodels.insert) .

But prediction i want to do through my java code . So below I have mentioned the code .

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.prediction.cmdline;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.prediction.Prediction;
import com.google.api.services.prediction.PredictionScopes;
import com.google.api.services.prediction.model.Input;
import com.google.api.services.prediction.model.Input.InputInput;
import com.google.api.services.prediction.model.Output;
import com.google.api.services.prediction.model.Training;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * @author Yaniv Inbar
 */
public class PredictionSample {

  /**
   * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
   * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "senti-model/1.0";

  static final String MODEL_ID = "senti-model";
  //static final String STORAGE_DATA_LOCATION = "enter_bucket/language_id.txt";

  /** Directory to store user credentials. */
  private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/prediction_sample");

  /**
   * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
   * globally shared instance across your application.
   */
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(PredictionSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.out.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=prediction "
          + "into prediction-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        Collections.singleton(PredictionScopes.PREDICTION)).setDataStoreFactory(
        dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  private static void run() throws Exception {
    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    // authorization
    Credential credential = authorize();
    Prediction prediction = new Prediction.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    //train(prediction);
    predict(prediction, "Is this sentence in English?");
    predict(prediction, "Â¿Es esta frase en EspaÃ±ol?");
    predict(prediction, "Est-ce cette phrase en FranÃ§ais?");
  }

   private static void error(String errorMessage) {
    System.err.println();
    System.err.println(errorMessage);
    System.exit(1);
  }

  private static void predict(Prediction prediction, String text) throws IOException {
    Input input = new Input();
    InputInput inputInput = new InputInput();
    inputInput.setCsvInstance(Collections.<Object>singletonList(text));
    input.setInput(inputInput);
    Output output = prediction.trainedmodels().predict(MODEL_ID, input).execute();
    System.out.println("Text: " + text);
    System.out.println("Predicted language: " + output.getOutputLabel());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      run();
      // success!
      return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

This is the error I am getting while executing this code:

```
Jun 24, 2014 2:11:09 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\deepesh.shetty\.store\prediction_sample
Jun 24, 2014 2:11:09 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\deepesh.shetty\.store\prediction_sample
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.prediction.cmdline.PredictionSample.predict(PredictionSample.java:157)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.prediction.cmdline.PredictionSample.run(PredictionSample.java:100)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.prediction.cmdline.PredictionSample.main(PredictionSample.java:164)
```

Help me in issue . 
Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

.../jre/lib/security/java.policy

Can you try giving permission to all as below ?

```
grant{
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: This is how it is :                                                grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

Comment: You can work backwards..If giving all permissions work, fine tune it to give permissions only for required files/jars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `client_secrets.json`, this creates a tiny file in your user folder - in my case it is `C:\Users\myUser\.store\calendar_sample`, the file is **StoredCredential**, so you can delete this file and try again the sample, this will work, when you run again your program it will ask you to grant permission again for your google account.