# Google Drive API Error "WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner/everbody"

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been trying to allow a program I am writing to access Google Drive Applications. I have gotten the client secrets information successfully, and have copy and pasted the example code and tried using it to successfully authenticate my program and use the google drive API.

However, when it gets to the line

```
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

I get this error. This error has been posted about before, and I've tried essentially every solution. I've elevated both my program and all the java.exe files to administrator and tried running the program and I still got this error.

The full error is:

```
    Oct 03, 2015 11:48:39 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
    WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: D:\directory
    Oct 03, 2015 11:48:39 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
    WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: D:\directory
```

I've also tried overriding the setPermissionToOwnerOnly when I instantiated the FileDataStoreFactory but that failed as well.

I have tried the following solutions:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634827/warning-unable-to-change-permissions-for-everybody
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382069/error-while-executing-google-prediction-api-command-line-sample
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/-7BH7Z40gkw (where the client secret data was hard coded into the program, this is bad, I know, but it didn't work anyway)
```

I don't know what to do at this point. I am running my program off a flash drive, and I tried running it off my computer as well, but it still failed. I am using NetBeans 8.0.2.

The error comes up as a warning, so maybe there is some way to just ignore the warning and proceed? That could be a solution, but I've researched and I'm not sure if that's a possibility. I am running windows 10 if that matters.

Comment: If you've received an answer that solves your question, remember to take the time to "Accept" the answer.

Comment: The warning can be ignored. The issue is different. Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34797777/617277

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the Drive REST API example [Java Quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java) through Eclipse and is working fine. It does requires a bit of setup time if you have not install [Gradle](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/) (also Eclipse Marketplace has a plugin for Gradle).

To your point, I did get the same warning messages. However, it happened for me during the load client secret in the *authorize()* method.

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
        DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

I suspect this is where your issue is happening. Since, I am not able to see that part from your code snippet, have a look at where your *client_secret.json* file is located.

Hope this helps. Good luck!