# Google Drive java netbeans quickstart error "setPermissionsToOwnerOnly"

Tags: java, netbeans, google-drive-api

The application is a desktop application and is designed to work with google drive.

I have followed the quickstart guide on [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) without using the Gradle. I am working with jars and have added the library for google drive.

I have landed into a problem of setPermissionsToOwnerOnly error and have looked at multiple posts on stackoverflow and various other sites and still have not been able to resolve the problem.

few solutions I have read about are listed below and all of them do not seem to be working.

- stop the process
- change the directory
- place client_secret.json in build/classes/main or build/classes/main/resources/
- clear the .credentials folder

Here is my coding as from google developers site

```
package UploadToDrive;



import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DriveQuickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Drive API Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\TESTINGS\\build\\classes\\main\\resources\\client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = getDriveService();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
             .setPageSize(10)
             .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
             .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the error message that is displayed when I run the desktop application on netbeans.

```
    Jul 25, 2016 3:52:03 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\SilverFear\.credentials\drive-java-quickstart.json
Jul 25, 2016 3:52:03 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\SilverFear\.credentials\drive-java-quickstart.json
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at UploadToDrive.DriveQuickstart.authorize(DriveQuickstart.java:77)
    at UploadToDrive.DriveQuickstart.getDriveService(DriveQuickstart.java:100)
    at UploadToDrive.DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:109)
C:\Users\SilverFear\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Please could someone help me out with this or tell me what I am doing wrong. I have been searching myself for a solution and just can't find any.

Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634827/warning-unable-to-change-permissions-for-everybody / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925164/google-drive-api-error-warning-unable-to-change-permissions-for-owner-everbody.

Comment: @d.datul1990 I have already been to that question and tried the answers which is present there. The reason why I have asked it is because as mentioned above in my question, I have already tried those solutions and they did not work. Thanks